# Error: Creating Virtual Environment (with virtualenv) while setting up python Selenium via Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck trying to create a virtual environment. The instructions for this step are:

Create a new VirtualEnv in the directory for your Selenium files:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.0 venv
```

After checking my version of python I get: `"Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)"`.
I tried replacing '3.0' with '3.6':

```
Wills-MacBook-Pro-2:my_selenium_project willdudek$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv
```

and get this error message:

> The path /usr/bin/python3.6 (from --python=/usr/bin/python3.6) does
>   not exist

I also tried quitting terminal and reopening (so I'm not in my_selenium_project), importing virtualenv in Python, then trying to create a virtual environment using `virtualenv my_selenium_project` and that didn't work.

Do I need a different command since I'm running Python through Anaconda?

Comment: The `-p` argument takes an executable as an argument. If there is no `/usr/bin/python3.6` then that command won't work. You probably just want `/usr/bin/python` or even `python` as the argument to `-p`.

Comment: Thanks. I never resolved the error with that approach, but I was able to successfully create a virtual environment using:
`sudo su`
`pip3 install virtualenv`
`virtualenv venv`
`source venv/bin/activate`

which worked for me.